# Android and awt robot keyPress, mousePress

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app that runs in the background. I want it to click/touch some points on screen as well as write some text automatically (example, open Browser, type google.com, search something). But as I am informed, there is no awt Robot in android so, how is this possible? Because I can't use keyPress, mouseMove and mousePress/mouseRelease commands...

Comment: nothing good can come of forcing users to go places they dont choose....

Comment: lol? I am not making apps and sell them. All I want is to make a fun app and make MY life a bit more convenient

Answer (score 0):

it is against android policie to do the things you ask. you may not make clicks for users and you may not present them with pop-ups, whether its google that pops- up or not.

Comment: again, I am not selling apps. I am complete noob, all I want is make only one that can make my life a bit more convenient. anyways, thanks